# tcpdump to monitor snmp from subnet causing syntax error

Tags: tcpdump, syntax, snmp

I'm trying to monitor SNMP from 2 hosts on the same subnet; 10.52.17.31 and 10.52.17.32.  They are on the only machines on that subnet.

Using the following commands I receive a syntax error:

```
tcpdump -i eth2 net 10.52.17.0/24 -nn -v port '(161 or 162)'
or 
tcpdump -i eth2 -nn -v port '(161 or 162)' net 10.52.17.0/24 
or
tcpdump net 10.52.17.0/24 -i eth2 -nn -v port '(161 or 162)'
```

I works if i do...  `tcpdump -i eth2 net 10.52.17.0/24 -nn -v` but adding the port switch in the command causes the error.

I'm able to pretty much accomplish what I want with...  `tcpdump -i eth2 -nn -v port '(161 or 162)'  | grep 10.52.17` but I'm not crazy about that solution, and want to understand the proper use of tcpdump better. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think `port` works with a boolean expression. Try `'net 10.52.17 and (port 161 or port 162)'`.

Comment: Well, I was wrong, but `tcpdump 'port (161 or 162)' and net 10.11.12` certainly works here on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: That work.  Guess I'm confused about when I need to use ***and***

Comment: The pcap filter syntax used by tcpdump is sufficiently complex to frequently require trial-and-error to get it right. Have fun tracing!

Comment: I got free of the error with `sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 net 10.52.17.0/24 -nn -v and "port 161 or 162"`, but I can't say it does whst it's supposed to do.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks.  Good to know that it's not just me.  Guess I'll just have to accept that there's going to be a certain amount failure before I get things right.   I can live with that.